# How to make an SQL query to get only 1 row with specific data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT work_from, work_until, restaurant_id, from_date, to_date FROM restaurant_working_times
WHERE restaurant_id = ?
  and restaurant_id is not null
  and `week_day` = ?
  and `is_closed` = 0
  and ((from_date <= ? and until_date >= ?) or (from_date is null and until_date is null))
ORDER BY (from_date IS NOT NULL AND until_date IS NOT NULL) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The logic of the query is to get opening hours for the restaurant. There're 2 types of open hours:

- Permanent. It is default opening hours for restaurant for every day
- Specific. It is a row that contains the range between `from_date` and `until_date` dates when this schedule works.

Query gets the rows which:

- has current day of week in ISO format ISO (1 => Monday etc)
- where current date is in the range of `from_date` and `until_date` (custom restaurant schedule) **or** `from_date` and `until_date` equals to `NULL` (default restaurant schedule)
- where `is_closed` column equals to `0` (if the column equals to `0`, then the restaurant closed today)

And then I sort the result by `from_date` and `until_date` and limit the result by 1 row, so if restaurant has a custom schedule, then I'll take the row that contains custom schedule for today. If no, I'll take the row with default schedule.

**The problem:** this query allows to get opening hours for certain restaurant (I have to execute this query for each restaurant). It makes the `N+1` problem if I want to get the list of the open restaurants.

**Question:** what is the query that will find open restaurants?

`restaurant_working_times` table schema

```
+----+---------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| id | restaurant_id | week_day | from_date  | until_date | from_hour | until_hour | is_closed |
+----+---------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|  8 |             5 |        1 | NULL       | NULL       | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 15 |             5 |        1 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-10 | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
|  9 |             5 |        2 | NULL       | NULL       | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 16 |             5 |        2 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-10 | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 10 |             5 |        3 | NULL       | NULL       | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 17 |             5 |        3 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-10 | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 11 |             5 |        4 | NULL       | NULL       | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 18 |             5 |        4 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-10 | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 12 |             5 |        5 | NULL       | NULL       | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 19 |             5 |        5 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-10 | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 13 |             5 |        6 | NULL       | NULL       | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 20 |             5 |        6 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-10 | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 14 |             5 |        7 | NULL       | NULL       | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
| 21 |             5 |        7 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-10 | 10:00:00  | 22:00:00   |         0 |
+----+---------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

I want to get the output with the following columns:

```
id, restaurant_id, from_hour, until_hour
```

There should be only open restaurants, so open restaurant means that we found the row with `restaurant_id` where current time greater than `from_hour` and less than `until_hour`. Also I should repeat that "custom" schedule has a higher priority than "default" schedule. "custom" schedule means that `from_date` and `until_date` are not equal to `null`. If there's no custom schedule for the day — we take "default" schedule, if there's no default schedule — the restaurant is closed today.

Comment: Please add table Schema with sample data and desired output.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra just updated it now

Comment: You probably just need two or three queries: get specific times for all restaurants for today, and get permanent times for all restaurants. Then outer join the two and take the most specific times you have for each restaurant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prioritization problem.  For each restaurant, you want the row with dates to have the priority.  To accomplish this, you can use window functions:

```
SELCT rwt.
FROM (SELECT rwt.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rwt.restaurant_id
                                ORDER BY (rwt.from_date is not null AND rwt.until_date is not null) DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM restaurant_working_times rwt
      WHERE rwt.restaurant_id IS NOT NULL AND
            rwt.week_day = ? AND
            rwt.is_closed = 0 AND
            (rwt.from_date <= ? AND rwt.until_date >= ? OR 
             rwt.from_date is null AND rwt.until_date is null
            )
     ) rwt
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, you can phrase this as:

```
select rwt.*
from restaurant_working_times rwt
where rwt.restaurant_id IS NOT NULL AND
      rwt.week_day = ? AND
      rwt.is_closed = 0 AND
      (rwt.from_date <= ? AND rwt.until_date >= ?)
union all
select rwt.*
from restaurant_working_times rwt
where rwt.restaurant_id IS NOT NULL AND
      rwt.week_day = ? AND
      rwt.is_closed = 0 AND
      (rwt.from_date is null AND rwt.until_date is null) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from restaurant_working_times rwt2
                  where rwt2.restaurant_id IS NOT NULL AND
                        rwt2.week_day = rwt.week_day AND
                        rwt2.is_closed = 0 and
                        (rwt2.from_date <= ? AND rwt2.until_date >= ?)
                ) ;
```

Note that the number of parameters has changed.  This is a case where named parameters would be helpful.